# The identical code, on the same place on another page - doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

At the bottom of index.php I have this code and it works:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#tbAlegro").click(function() {
    window.location = 'alegro.php';
});
</script>
```

At the bottom of alegro.php I have the same code and it doesn't work:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#logoCh").click(function() {
    window.location = 'index.php';
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is jQuery included on both of the pages?

Comment: Do you have an element with id="logoCh" on the page?

Comment: Thanks. jQuery was missing on the second page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Is jQuery being loaded on alegro.php
2. Is there an element with an ID of `logoCh` on alegro.php
3. Are there any javascript errors?

Comment: Jack, Jquery is missing on the second page. Thanks a lot. Solved.